# How do I set the click method on CARD VIEW in VIEW PAGER that using ArrayList<> to add the object?

Tags: android, arraylist, onclicklistener, cardview

## *I want to make clicklistener on cardview in my viewpager to startActivity(Intent)*

> i've tried to make clicklistener with position in setOnPageChangeListener method, but it does not work for me. Please help.

I want to set Intent on cardview.clicklistener, but i don't understand how to set by position, wheter using swith or if method

HERE MY ACTIVITY CODE :

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
Adapter adapter;
List<Model> models;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.cardViewLogin);

    //ImageViewPager
    models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.m,"title", "desc"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.d,"title", "desc"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.a,"title", "desc"));

    adapter = new Adapter(models,this);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setPadding(130,0,130,0);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(final int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

HERE MY ADAPTER CODE :

```
public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

private List<Model> models;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;

public Adapter(List<Model> models, Context context) {
    this.models = models;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return models.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) 
 {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item,container,false);

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title, desc;

    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    desc = view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

    imageView.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage());
    title.setText(models.get(position).getTitle());
    desc.setText(models.get(position).getDesc());

    container.addView(view,0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, 
 @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View)object);
}
```

HERE IS MY item.xml CODE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardViewLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/hourglass"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

HERE IS MY XML ACTIVITY LAYOUT CODE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".UserLoginActivity">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick listener of cardView

cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int pos=viewPager.getCurrentItem();
          //used switch case
             switch (pos) {
                 case 0:
                 //Do whatever you want
                 break;
                 case 1:
                 //Do whatever you want
                 break;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay, but i get this error : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: because of you are defined cardview in adapter item.xml layout and yo are getting cardview reference in activity, get the cardview reference  and implement onclick listener in the instantiateItem method of adapter